# Load Balancing with Nginx, Docker, and a PEP

Tags: nginx

I'm am working on load balancing traffic for a chat application that is running inside Docker. This setup essentially has two servers, one is a PEP server and the other is the application server. The PEP authenticates users and sends the HTTPS traffic to the Nginx proxy on the chat server and distributes the traffic between 5 containers using ip_hash for persistence. Or at least it should.

```
upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  server 127.0.0.1:3002;
  server 127.0.0.1:3003;
  server 127.0.0.1:3004;
```

}

The problem is that all the traffic is essentially coming from the PEP server (i.e. same IP) and so the ip_hash algorithm is sending all traffic to one container rather than load balancing the traffic.

I apologize if this is common knowledge, but is there a workaround that would keep persistency while still balancing the load?

**UPDATE**

I have captured packets with WireShark and can see that the Forward-For address is the user and I have added the following to the default.conf, however, this has not solved the load balancing issues I'm having.

```
    location /chat {

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://backend/chat;
    proxy_redirect off;
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index  index.html index.htm;
}
```